# .NET assembly internal loading

Tags: .net, clr, internals

Could someone explain me in depth how the system loads an .NET assembly.
I mean :

- what dlls are used : I supposed first mscoree.dll, next mscorwks.dll and mscorjit.dll
- what methods in these dlls ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Homework? Nothing wrong with homework questions, but they should be flagged as such.

Answer (score 3):

Look in "CLR via C#" book by Jeffrey Richter, chapter "CLR Hosting"